# grep behaving differently on Fedora vs Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, fedora, grep

So when I run this in Fedora I'm seeing this:

```
$ ls hmm_data/indivA12_AATAAG/refs/par1/
2R-orths.alleles  2R-ref.alleles
$ ls hmm_data/indivA12_AATAAG/refs/par1/ | grep -F '-ref.alleles'
2R-ref.alleles
```

But when I run on Ubuntu (same data) I don't get any results from the grep:

```
$ ls hmm_data/indivA12_AATAAG/refs/par1/
2R-orths.alleles  2R-ref.alleles
$ ls hmm_data/indivA12_AATAAG/refs/par1/ | grep -F '-ref.alleles'
```

Any ideas what could be going on?  How can I come up with something that will work the same on both systems?

Comment: How about `ls *-ref.alleles` ?

Comment: @glennjackman, I thought of that but someone did exactly that and commented that line out in the bash script I'm trying to fix :-)  I can only assume they had a reason ...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
grep -F '-ref.alleles'
```

is equivalent to:

```
grep -F -ref.alleles
```

(none of the characters between the apostrophes are shell metacharacters, so quoting them has no effect.)

This is in turn equivalent to:

```
grep -F -r -e f.alleles
```

by normal parsing of `-` prefixed options. The `-e` option takes an argument, but `-F` and `-r` don't.

Since you didn't specify any files to grep, the default behavior is to act on stdin... except that the `-r` option makes no sense so it defaults to searching `.` (the current directory) recursively instead and ignores stdin. In some versions.

You need to use the `--` "no more options" indicator before a regexp that starts with `-` as in

```
grep -F -- -ref.alleles
```

I tracked down the point where the behavior of `-r` with no file arguments changed. It was in version 2.11, released March 2, 2012. [See the release announcement.](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7132)

The git commits which affected the behavior are [this one](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=faf6ea13b3281a2004f5bfd1487708d1ba50a6c5) and [this one](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=d1d7245219bc56e6a4f25c18d6f8f4b4b9bb42d6).

If you run `grep --version` on your two machines, I'm sure you'll find that one of them is on the wrong side of 2.11

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the research all the way to the version where the behaviour changed.

Comment: wow thanks.  You're right, I've got grep 2.6.3 vs grep 2.14.

Answer (score 6):

The leading `-` is the problem. To get same results add `--`:

```
grep -F -- '-ref.alleles'
```

From `man bash`:

```
A -- signals the end of options and disables further option
processing. Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames
and arguments.
```

Comment: Why does it differ on Ubuntu and Fedora? Shouldn't it give the same negative result on both of them?

Comment: Thanks.  If this command is to be piped into another command, would the -- cause any problems there? Or does -- just apply to the command where it shows up?

Comment: The bash man page isn't really relevant. It explains the treatment of `--` on bash's own command line, which is independent from grep's understanding of `--`. They work the same way because it's a common convention, but in general your shell's man page doesn't tell you anything about the meaning of arguments to other programs.

Answer (score 1):

Check .bashrc if there are any aliases on your grep command which override it's behaviour. Maybe it is the issue.
Also try grep without the "-F" param.